# Wordpress V4.7.31 install - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: wordpress, installation, mysql

installation fails with a bunch of the same errors. Summary below:

```
DB_Error
object
  (
    [error_message_prefix] => [MODE] => 1 [level] => 1024 [code] => -3 [MESSAGE] => db ERROR: CONSTRAINT violation [userinfo] =>
    INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_field
        ...
            [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot ADD
    OR
    UPDATE a child row: a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT fails (`****db****`.`civicrm_uf_field`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_uf_field_location_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`location_type_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_location_type` (`id`) ON
    DELETE SET NULL)] [backtrace] => array ( [0] => array ( [file] => /var/www/*******/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/db.php [line] => 985 [FUNCTION] => __construct [class] => pear_error [type] => -> [args] => array ( [0] => db ERROR: CONSTRAINT violation [1] => -3 [2] => 1 [3] => 1024 [4] =>
    INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_field
        ...
            [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot ADD
    OR
    UPDATE a child row: a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT fails (`****db****`.`civicrm_uf_field`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_uf_field_location_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`location_type_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_location_type` (`id`) ON
    DELETE SET NULL)] ) ) [1] => array ( [file] => /var/www/*******/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/pear.php [line] => 575 [FUNCTION] => __construct [class] => db_error [object] => db_error object *recursion* [type] => -> [args] => array ( [0] => -3 [1] => 1 [2] => 1024 [3] =>
    INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_field
        ...
    DELETE SET NULL)] ) ) [2] => array ( [file] => /var/www/*******/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/pear.php [line] => 223 [FUNCTION] => _raiseerror [class] => pear [object] => db_mysqli object ( [phptype] => mysqli [dbsyntax] => mysqli [features] => array ( [limit] => ALTER [new_link] => [numrows] => 1 [pconnect] => [PREPARE] => [ssl] => 1 [transactions] => 1 ) [errorcode_map] => array ( [1004] => -15 [1005] => -15 [1006] => -15 [1007] => -5 [1008] => -17 [1022] => -5 [1044] => -26 [1046] => -14 [1048] => -3 [1049] => -27 [1050] => -5 [1051] => -18 [1054] => -19 [1061] => -5 [1062] => -5 [1064] => -2 [1091] => -4 [1100] => -21 [1136] => -22 [1142] => -26 [1146] => -18 [1216] => -3 [1217] => -3 [1356] => -100 [1365] => -13 [1451] => -3 [1452] => -3 ) [connection] => mysqli object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $ID: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $ [client_version] => 50012 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 1452 [error] => cannot ADD
        ...
    DELETE SET NULL) [error_list] => array ( [0] => array ( [errno] => 1452 [SQLSTATE] => 23000 [error] => cannot ADD
        ...
    DELETE SET NULL) ) ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => localhost via unix socket [info] => [insert_id] => 2 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.0.34-mariadb-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => UPTIME: 2357 THREADS: 6 QUESTIONS: 57352 slow QUERIES: 0 OPENS: 15163 flush TABLES: 1 open TABLES: 400 queries per second AVG: 24.332 [SQLSTATE] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 1966 [warning_count] => 0 ) [dsn] => array ( [phptype] => mysqli [dbsyntax] => mysqli [username] => c1_rtf_wp_u1 [password] => idgemyrqkau@s9 [protocol] => tcp [hostspec] => localhost [port] => 3306 [socket] => [database] => ****db**** [new_link] => TRUE ) [autocommit] => 1 [transaction_opcount] => 0 [_db] => ****db**** [mysqli_flags] => array ( [1] => not_null [2] => primary_key [4] => unique_key [8] => multiple_key [16] => BLOB [32] => UNSIGNED [64] => ZEROFILL [512] => auto_increment [1024] => timestamp [2048] => SET [32768] => group_by ) [mysqli_types] => array ( [0] => DECIMAL [1] => TINYINT [2] => INT [3] => INT [4] => FLOAT [5] => DOUBLE [7] => timestamp [8] => BIGINT [9] => MEDIUMINT [10] => date [11] => time [12] => datetime [13] => year [14] => date [247] => enum [248] => SET [249] => TINYBLOB [250] => MEDIUMBLOB [251] => LONGBLOB [252] => BLOB [253] => VARCHAR [254] => CHAR [255] => geometry [16] => bit [246] => DECIMAL ) [fetchmode] => 1 [fetchmode_object_class] => stdclass [was_connected] => [last_query] =>
        ...
```

I Realise the above is cryptic but I'm hoping someone is able to give me some pointers. All system checks are green, had to disable one check as I run master/master SQL servers and there's no fix for that check apparently.

Thanks